# Xtext : not reading new line in case of MacOS

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

Below is my Xtext file. I have an input {TestData1}/n{TestData2}/n{TestData3}. In this case after parsing my data gets changed to {TestData1}{TestData2}{TestData3} (the /n gets removed as part of the FREE_TEXT ValueConverter. I don't want them to get removed. How should I modify my FREE_TEXT to accomodate this use case.
Please refer the **FREE_TEXT** terminal in the File, It is probably because of that one.

```
terminal EXT_INT: INT ('e'|'E')('-'|'+') INT;   

terminal FREE_TEXT:
    '}' ( '\\{' | !('{') )* ('{');
```

Code for parsing:

```
public class TestExpressionValueConverter extends DefaultTerminalConverters {
  @ValueConverter(rule = "FREE_TEXT")
  public IValueConverter<String> FREE_TEXT() {
    return new IValueConverter<String>() {
      @Override
      public String toValue(String string, INode node) throws ValueConverterException {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String result = string;
        if (result.startsWith("}" + lineSeparator)) {
          result = result.substring(1 + lineSeparator.length());
        } else if (result.startsWith("}")) {
          result = result.substring(1);
        }

        if (result.endsWith(lineSeparator + "{")) {
          result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1 - lineSeparator.length());
        } else if (result.endsWith("{")) {
          result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
        }
        result = result.replace("\\\\", "\\");
        result = result.replace("\\{", "{");
        // System.out.println("Convert " + string + " => " + result);
        return result;

      }

      @Override
      public String toString(String value) throws ValueConverterException {
        return "}" + value + "{";
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a minimal but complete reproducing grammar and sample model? do you have custom value converters implemented? how do you test

Comment: @ChristianDietrich attached the code that hits for parsing in my description.


here the RuleName is FREE_TEXT and the input }/n{ gets converted to empty String. I want it to return /n

Comment: i still dont have anything i can run to see the actual problem

Comment: also how is value converter implemented on your side?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I have updated the description and summary. Please do check and revert back.